# How do I draw an NSString at an angle?

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsstring

Is there a set of string attributes I can specify that will draw the text at an angle when I call:

```
[label drawAtPoint:textStart withAttributes:attributes];
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's an example that uses a transform to rotate the drawing context. Essentially it's just like setting a color or shadow, just make sure to use `-concat` instead of `-set`.

```
CGFloat rotateDeg = 4.0f;
NSAffineTransform *rotate = [[NSAffineTransform alloc] init];

[rotate rotateByDegrees:rotateDeg];
[rotate concat];

// Lock focus if needed and draw strings, images here.

[rotate release];
```

Comment: How do you undo this, for example draw one item at an angle and then the next back to normal.  I tried simply rotating a negative amount but that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 6):

NSString itself doesn't have rotation, but you can rotate the context. The string will always be drawn "horizontally" as far as the coordinate space goes, but what actual direction that corresponds to depends on the context. Just use NSAffineTransform to spin it as needed.