# I want to transform from rectangle view to curve view in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, view, transform, curve

I want to add label in view. Not rectangle label but curve label.

middle point lower with certain rate. Like  'U'. how??
I think using CGContextAddCurveToPoint. but how to use? in ios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with a UILabel, but if you take the string you want to draw into a curve, you can draw each letter and then alter the angle of the drawing using the technique in this related question:

[How do I draw an NSString at an angle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930313/how-do-i-draw-an-nsstring-at-an-angle)

(i.e. change the angle and position after every letter).