# How to put text with angle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I draw an NSString at an angle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930313/how-do-i-draw-an-nsstring-at-an-angle)

I am using

```
[@"mytext" drawInrect : CGRrectIntegral (rect) withFont:font];
```

to write text on a picture, How can i write the text with different angle each time? (its a rolling picture that should spin with the text).

Comment: for any _angel_ you should have very strong religion. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/930313/310903

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code rotates the `label`

```
- (IBAction)rotate:(id)sender {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:context];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(endAnimation)];
    CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(90.0f * (M_PI / 180.0f));
    self.label.transform = rotate;

    [UIView commitAnimations];  
}
```

Comment: Thanks! can i used the CGAffineTransformMakeRotation with NSString? or convert label to NSString?

Comment: This `label` is made by IB. You can also make it by `label = [[UILabel alloc] init]; label.text = @"fof fof fof";`